# How do I make diffrent color links on the same page using css?

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, hyperlink

I don't know what CSS code I should use to make them and the only other one I could find had to do with Class1 and Class2 but I don't even know how to implement those onto the link. I'm also doing it from an icon list widget on WordPress if that helps. Thanks in advance if you know what I am doing wrong. I think it has something to do with not labeling the links in a way

```
a.class1 {color:red;}
a.class1:link  {text-decoration: none; color: red;}
a.class1:visited {text-decoration: none; color: red;}
a.class1:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: red;}
a.class1:active {text-decoration: none; color: red;}


a.class2 {color:blue;}
a.class2:link {text-decoration: none; color: blue;}
a.class2:visited {text-decoration: none; color: blue;}
a.class2:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: blue;}
a.class2:active {text-decoration: none; color: blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, you can add custom CSS to your theme to achieve this. If you're using the default WordPress text widget, you can add your links like this:

```html
<a href="#" class="class1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="class2">Link 2</a>
```

Replace "#" with the actual URLs. This way, your links will inherit the styles you defined for class1 and class2 in your CSS.

Answer (score -2):

See this sample below, and use the div tag to call it in the body of your file.

```css
.city {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="city">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am really new to code so like picture talking to a little kid. (Wish there was a laughing emoji), But what do you have to do to the code and the link to make sure there different colors and would I put a different code on the other one I'm gonna try this one tho.

Comment: Hi, please provide a sample of your existing code and I will try to help from there.